# Apache HTTP Timeout on specific URL

Tags: apache, timeout, reverse-proxy

I have increased the timeout of our HTTPD Apache webserver. However now all calls have that increased timeout

Is there a way to set a Timeout for a specific url inside the same domain

eg

```
www.server.com/application1/* -> timeout default of 60s
www.server.com/application2/* -> timeout of 300s
```